# How to make a batch file wait for another batch file then continue with the rest of the file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
goto start
:start

if exist console.ccmf (
PAUSE
ren console.ccmf console.bat
ping 123.45.67.89 -n 1 -w 500 > nul
START /wait console.bat
ren console.bat console.ccmf
goto exit
)
```

I really want to find a way to do this without using a vbs script.
Just to fill you in... this is a program which renames a program and then starts it.. the aim is so when the said file closes it renames back to what it was and exits

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Just remove the pause. If you want you can replace the ping with `choice /t 10 /d y > nul`. That will wait for 10 seconds. Just replace the `10` with any number of seconds you want to pause. And the `> nul` hides all the output, so there is no noise on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `CALL` function. `Start` is really for launching windowed programs and opens another console, CALL stays in the one console window already open.

```
@echo off
goto start

:start
if exist console.ccmf (
    PAUSE
    ren console.ccmf console.bat
    ping 123.45.67.89 -n 1 -w 500 > nul
    CALL console.bat
    ren console.bat console.ccmf
    goto exit
)
```

Comment: Wait Just realised it doesn't work it doesn't continue with the rename after the program has exited @James K

Comment: Ok It works if I exit the program normally but if I do alt f4 or press the close button it doesn't run the code

Comment: @user1628565 ALT-F4 or the close button? Neither of those are proper ways to end a batch program, and explain why you were getting the "Terminate Batch Job? [Y/N]". I assume that you are doing this at the `PAUSE` command. Yes? Instead of that, use either `CHOICE /M "Quit?"` `if %errorlevel%==1 goto exit` or `set /p input=Press ENTER to Continue or Q+[ENTER] to Quit. [,Q]` `if "%input%"=="Q" goto exit`.

Comment: ok the batch job problem is fixed with the call and I know that there not how  your supposed to end files.. I'm just saying in case someone does do that I don't want it to not rename the file